# help with image class implementation

Tags: asp.net, oop

i build that class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CDN
{
public class Image
{
    #region Image parameters

    private int _PG_ID;
    private string _PG_FileName;
    private int _PG_ItemId;
    private int _TD_ID;
    private Boolean _PG_Visible;
    private string _PG_Caption;

    public int PG_ID
    {
        get { return _PG_ID; }
        set { _PG_ID = value; }
    }

    public string PG_FileName
    {
        get { return _PG_FileName; }
        set { _PG_FileName = value; }
    }

    public int PG_ItemId
    {
        get { return _PG_ItemId; }
        set { _PG_ItemId = value; }
    }

    public int TD_ID
    {
        get { return _TD_ID; }
        set { _TD_ID = value; }
    }

    public Boolean PG_Visible
    {
        get { return _PG_Visible; }
        set { _PG_Visible = value; }
    }

    public string PG_Caption
    {
        get { return _PG_Caption; }
        set { _PG_Caption = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public Image(int PG_ID)
    {
        GetImage(PG_ID);
    }

    public Image()
    {

    }

    private void GetImage(int PG_ID)
    {
            //TODO get image data from db and fill all parameters with the data
    }

    public int SaveImage(FileUpload fileUpload,string caption,Boolean visible,int toolId,int itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveImageToTemporaryFolder(fileUpload);
            return CreateImageOnDb(fileUpload.FileName, caption, visible, toolId, itemId);
         }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }      
    }

    private int CreateImageOnDb(string fileName, string caption, bool visible, int toolId, int itemId)
    {
        //TODO save image data on db return image id
        return 0;
    }

    private void SaveImageToTemporaryFolder(FileUpload fileUpload)
    {
        try
        {
            string savePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "\\upload\\pgallery\\";
            fileUpload.SaveAs(savePath + fileUpload.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How to pass the file?

EDITED:
in the function SaveImage i pass a FileUpload control.
I want to use the class like this:
when uploading image to craete a new Image object and to pass him all data, but how can i transfer him the file.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.PG_Caption = "my file name";
img.PG_Visible = True;
img.SaveImage(file);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, it's not clear what your wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter your SaveImage function to take a Stream and pass in like this:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileUpload.FileBytes))
{
    img.SaveImage(stream);
}
```

Comment: there is a mistake in fileUpload.FileData and then in File.OpenRead()

Comment: Yeah I had two different thoughts going on in my head - updated the code.